# Nodejs - Hide window from spawned bat file process | Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, child-process, spawn

I have a bat file which is just:

```
ping localhost -t
```

When I do:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const c = cp.spawn(
  'test.bat',
  [],
  {stdio: ['ignore', log, log], detached: true, shell: false, windowsHide: true}
)
```

It opens up a new command prompt and outputs to there, I want it to show no window and also to redirect the output to the fd i specified.

If I do:

```
const c = cp.spawn(
  'ping', 
  ['localhost', '-t'],
  {stdio: ['ignore', log, log], detached: true}
);
```

**No** shell pops up and the command works behind the scene logging to the specified fd.

But I can't use this since I'm actually trying to run a more complex bat file with a bunch of commands.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the doc says, https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows:

> On Windows, however, .bat and .cmd files are not executable on their own without a terminal

Nevertheless, you can use a tip from this post https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window:

=== test.vbs ===

```
Dim WinScriptHost
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "test.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

=== your nodejs script ===

```
spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'test.vbs'], {
    shell: false,
    detached: true,
    stdio: 'ignore',
    windowsHide: true
}).unref()
```